# What does the echo command do?

Tags: command-line, bash, echo

I am fairly new to Linux and all I know for sure about the command `echo` is that when you type a word after it, such as `echo Linux!`, it prints out `Linux!`. Is there anything else `echo` does?

I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: `echo` is usually a built-in command provided by the shell; see your shell's manual page for details. There is also an independent program named `echo` (`/bin/echo`), of course, with its own [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/echo.1.html).

Comment: One important thing to know about `echo` is that you probably shouldn't use it. Use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `echo` is:

```
echo [option(s)] [string(s)]
```

You can pass options to it in order to have a better intended results. As example, `-e` acts as interpretation of escaped characters that are backslashed. Using option `\b` – backspace with backslash interpretor `-e` which removes all the spaces in between.So when running the following command:

```
$ echo -e "Tecmint \bis \ba \bcommunity \bof \bLinux \bNerds"
```

That produces:

```
TecmintisacommunityofLinuxNerds
```

You can run `man [command]` to know what are its options.

```
man echo
```

**Edit**:

According to @Zanna comment which is attached to this answer. When we `man echo`, we are not showing the manual of the built-in `echo` . To read short documentation about the built-in `echo` we need to run `help echo` .

Comment: note that the `man` page that comes up when you type `man echo` is not the `man` page for the builtin `echo` you are normally using in an interactive shell, but for `/bin/echo`. The `man` page does mention this... To read the short documentation for the Bash builtin `echo`, you can run `help echo`. See [Why is there a /bin/echo and why would I want to use it?](//askubuntu.com/q/960822)

Comment: Oh thank you for such a beneficial information.